# Expectation value of 2^X.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Three players throw a dice and sum the values. Then 2 is raised to the obtained degree.
What's the expected value of the obtained random variable? Enter the value:

For example, let:

On three dice we get 1, 2 and 5 respectively. Then the sum is 8. Hence:

$x_{(1,2,5)} = 2^8$

we need expectation value of:

$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6\sum_{k=1}^6 x_{(i,j,k)} * p_{i,j,k}$

Comment: By direct computation, $9261$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can write:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{6^3}\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6\sum_{k=1}^6 2^{i+j+k}$$

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{6^3}\sum_{i=1}^62^i\sum_{j=1}^62^j\sum_{k=1}^6 2^{k}$$

If $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k$ then $f(n) = 2^{n+1} - 2$, proof left as an exercise to the reader (hint: induction).

$$E[X] = \frac{f(6)^3}{6^3}= {\left(\frac{2^7 - 2}{6}\right)}^3 = 21^3 = 9261$$